# Kaminari pager not working with Sinatra and Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid, bundler, kaminari

Can't get Kaminari to work with Sinatra and Mongoid.  I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError at /api/events
undefined method `page' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x007fccb7828c38>
```

Here is minimal code to get the error:

**Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'kaminari-mongoid'
gem 'kaminari-sinatra'
```

**server.rb**

```
require 'mongoid'
require 'sinatra'

class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
end

get '/events' do
  Event.desc(:id).page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

I have tried `require 'kaminari'`, `require 'kaminari-sinatra'`, `require 'kaminari-mongoid'`, all to no avail (I get `LoadError`s).  I've also tried `register Kaminari::Helpers::SinatraHelpers` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/issues/486), which also failed.

I've followed the [instructions](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/wiki) in detail, and have scoured Google and StackOverflow to no avail.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415438) didn't work.  I can't help thinking I'm missing something easy; I'm not a Ruby veteran.  My hunch is it's something with Bundler. Any idea?

Comment: I am using gem `kaminari` (without `-mongoid`) version "0.15" with mongoid and it is working fine in my application. https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the problem as well. Unfortunately, kaminari-mongoid has a rails dependency (you can look in the gemspec file here: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari-mongoid/blob/master/kaminari-mongoid.gemspec). Therefore, it is not possible to use both kaminari-sinatra and kaminari-mongoid.

This solved my problem. https://github.com/ajsharp/mongoid-pagination. Add it to your Gemfile and install with Bundler.

In your app.rb file, `require 'mongoid-pagination'`

Comment: Updated it as I've found a solution.